# Extracting Lower, Middle, and Higher Distancefrom Array

Tags: php, arrays

The goal is to extract minimum, middle and highest distance. the lowest distance was successfully achieved. however the middle and highest distance is more complex.

Array content is shown below:
Array name: $array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Reduit
                    [1] => Curepipe
                )

            [distance] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Reduit
                            [1] => Ebe
                        )

                    [1] => Bees Village
                    [2] => Phoen Trunk Rd
                    [3] => Riv,Phoenix
                    [4] => St l Rd
                    [5] => Geoes Guibert St
                    [6] => Curepipe
                )

            [distance] => 151
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Reduit
                            [1] => Riv,Phoenix
                        )

                    [1] => St l Rd
                    [2] => Geoes Guibert St
                    [3] => Curepipe
                )

            [distance] =>50
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Reduit
                            [1] => Ebene
                        )

                    [1] => Belles Village
                    [2] => Phoenix Trunk Rd
                    [3] => Riverside,Phoenix
                    [4] => St Paul Rd
                    [5] => Georges Guibert St
                    [6] => Curepipe
                )

            [distance] => 101
        )

)
```

Can someone tell me where am wrong . My workings are

```
$current = $array[0]['distance'];

for($middleDistance=1;$middleDistance<$total;$middleDistance++){

    $next = $array[($middleDistance)]['distance'];

    if ($next<$current){

            $current = $next;

            print_r($current);

            if($current>50&&$current<100){


            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not sort the array by value and get the min/mid/max from that? If you truly want the closest to middle element you would have to compare the 2 middle-most elements in the case of an even number of distances. Also, I didn't make use of them here, but take note of PHPs min and max functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

```
$arr = array(200, 151, 50, 101);                                                                                                                    

sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);                                                                                                                           

if (count($arr)) {                                                                                                                                  
  $min = current($arr);                                                                                                                             
  $max = end($arr);                                                                                                                                 

  $mid = $arr[round(count($arr) / 2) - 1];                                                                                                                
}
```